# Creating setup project in .NET with MS Access

Tags: .net, ms-access, setup-project

I am doing a Windows forms application.I am using MS Access as database.I need to create a setup project of my application.Where can i keep this mdb file while creating the setup project so that both direction data flow will be possible after installing my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setup can install an .mdb file just like it can copy any other file, but I'm not sure what you mean by

*both direction data flow will be possible after installing my application*

you don't expect the installed .mdb to be a replica of a master database that automatically synchronizes data for you, do you?

You need to do a lot more work to get data synchronization going.

---

In response to comments,
If you can't get the setup to install a file you need in c:\somewhere, have the setup install it in the application directory.  Then, when your .exe runs, have the .exe check if your file exists in c:\somewhere.  If it doesn't, have your .exe copy the file from the application directory where the setup can install it to the place your .exe expects it, c:\somewhere.  Then your application can use it.  You add another check for the file your .exe needs before your .exe uses it.

Comment: Actually i need to install the .mdb file in the C directory.how can i make the setup project to install the .mdb file in the specified location other than Application folder?

Comment: if you're having trouble getting the setup to do it, consider having the application do it during startup.  If the mdb it wants on c:\ isn't there, move it from the application directory (or copy it) to where you want it.

Comment: can u explain me what you are telling about?

Comment: Now its working for me.I installed the .mdb file in the Common Files folder.Thanks